# SQL Select and Group by in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
Track   Actor                  Movie
1       Katherine Hepburn      Guess Who's Coming to Dinner
2       Katherine Hepburn      Guess Who's Coming to Dinner
3       Katherine Hepburn      On Golden Pond
4       Katherine Hepburn      The Lion in Winter
5       Bette Davis            What Ever Happened to Baby Jane?
6       Bette Davis            The Letter
7       Bette Davis            The Letter
...
100     Omar Shariff           Lawrence of Arabia
```

Need to write a code in python to select all the actors that have starred in more than one movie and append their names to a list.

A python equivalent of the following SQL query.

```
SELECT Actor, count(DISTINCT Movie)
FROM table
GROUP by Actor
HAVING count(DISTINCT Movie) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method for `DISTINCT` movie values:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Actor','Movie'])
```

Now For grouping and aggregrating use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method and chain [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method to it:

```
result=df.groupby('Actor').agg(count=('Movie','count'))
```

Finally make use of boolean masking and check your condition(count>1):

```
result=result[result['count']>1]
```